# importing plugin w/ settings from one WP installation to another

Tags: plugins

Is there a way to import plugins (and their settings) from one WP installation to another?
I've found various tools and tutorials for exporting/importing entire WP installs, posts and pages, etc. but nothing for plugins & plugin settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As every plugin is unique in how and where it stores its data there is no standard process to do this. Some plugins might still offer an import/export functionality themselves. I'm sorry but WordPress doesn't offer the functionality out of the box.

Comment: Wow, what a bummer. I figured(hoped?) the plugins would conform to a similar process to ex/importing other content. Thanks anyway.